# Handling of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP vs. DATETIME field in query

Tags: sql, mariadb, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm struggling with handling of time values in a MariaDB 10.3. In particular, I can't make sense of when a time value is converted according to a configured time zone and when it isn't.

```sql
CREATE TABLE aoeui (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO aoeui () VALUES ();

SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as ts FROM aoeui;

-- Note: I'm on CEST, which is currently +02:00 and the goal of this value
-- is just to be different from that to illustrate the behaviour.
SET TIME_ZONE = '+08:00';

SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as ts FROM aoeui;

DROP TABLE aoeui;

-- reset timezone, so you can re-run the code in the same session
SET TIME_ZONE = 'SYSTEM';
```

*Note: The insert and the two queries easily run within a second, so any timestamps should differ at most by that short runtime, I'll call them equal here despite this not being 100% true (and a racecondition) in reality.*

Note 2: The two values `2023-08-15 14:26:47 +0800` and `2023-08-15 08:26:47 +0200` describe the same point in time, just in two different ways.

In the first `SELECT` query, the result shows the same point in time twice. In the second query, the result contains the same point in time twice, only represented for a different timezone. However, this second query only gets the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value correct, the representation of the value retrieved from the table is the same as in the first query.

## Example Session

```
Database changed
MariaDB [tmp]> CREATE TABLE aoeui (
    ->     id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.030 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> INSERT INTO aoeui () VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.004 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as ts FROM aoeui;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | created             | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2023-08-15 08:26:47 | 2023-08-15 08:26:47 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> SET TIME_ZONE = '+08:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as ts FROM aoeui;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | created             | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2023-08-15 08:26:47 | 2023-08-15 14:26:47 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> DROP TABLE aoeui;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.010 sec)
```

You can see in the second query, the hours changed from `08` to `14`, but just for one of the results. I would have expected it to change in both.

Comment: `SET TIME_ZONE = '+08:00';` only sets the session variable. The global timezone remains unchanged and your system timezone might not be set to +02:00

Comment: Apparently you assume that changing the time zone will corrupt stored data?!

Comment: @PaulMaxwell, I'm aware of session variables. Since the above all runs in one session ([mcve]), that is fine, and the setting also shows an effect.

Comment: @GeorgRichter, no, not currupt. I'd expect it to influence how it is displayed or represented on wire. 9 o'clock at +02:00 is the same point in time as 7 o'clock UTC, even though they are written differently. I'll try to clarify that in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB doesn't store the timezone in TIMESTAMP types.

If you change the time_zone within MariaDB subsequent operations will use the new time, but existent data will not be changed.

If you have to work with multiple timezones you should store your time as an UTC timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE aoeui (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                   created DATETIME DEFAULT UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

To display the time depending on your timezone, use `CONVERT_TZ()` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(created, "+0:00", @@timezone) FROM aoeui;
```

For more information I would suggest to read the [DATETIME documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time-zones/) or watch [Properly Handling Time and Date](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV8q_mbZzEo) from Andrew Hutchings.

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say "in TIMESTAMP types", that includes the `DATETIME` type used in the table, right?

Comment: Yes, these includes all date and time types, they are internally stored in MYSQL_TIME structure, which doesn't have timezone information. (see https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.2/include/mysql_time.h#L48)

Comment: That would explain it, I guess, need to sleep over it. In summary, that would mean that the storage format is timezone-dependent while it excludes that information. That comes as a surprise, because I can't think of a good reason for that.